# IF AND statement only outputs ELSE statement Python

Tags: python, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements, nan

I have a function that generates different dataframes, the 3rd dataframe causes an error because it contains a final row of NaN values at the bottom.

I tried an if-else conditional statement to remove the row of NaN values, but everytime I do, it keeps outputting the NaN values.

```
ma = 1
year = 3
df

if ma > 0 and year == 3:
    df[0:-1]
else:
    df
```

I also tried a nested if statement, but that produced the same output of NaN values.

```
ma_path = "SMA"
year_path = "YEAR_3"

if ma_path == ["SMA"]:
    if year_path == ["YEAR_3"]:
        df[0:-1]
    else:
        df
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I've missed. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of a column or of a row? If you are using `pandas.DataFrame`, using `df[]` is to access columns, not rows. Use `df.loc[]` to access rows.

Comment: Hey Silveris, I was trying to remove the NaN values in the bottom row of my dataframe. Fortunately my problem is solved. I was just dumb, forgot to assign df = df[0:-1] in the if-and statement.

Answer (score 5):

`df[0:-1]` does not change the values that `df` currently contains. If you want to remove the last item of `df`, you need to assign the slice back to the name:

```
df = df[0:-1]
```

If df was an ordinary list, you could also remove items with `pop`.

```
df.pop()
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! I should have realized I needed to assign the updated df to df. Doh! >.<